# Node.jsproblem require addon in parent directory in Windows

Tags: node.js, windows

On Linux, all of this works naturally, but on Windows, we have serious problems with requiring an *add-on* if it's the parent path, or a subdirectory of the parent path.

So, if I'm in the *parent* directory and run node with the following:

```
require("./subdir/build/Release/myAddon");
```

it loads beautifully!

But, let say I go in another subdirectory and run node with the following:

```
require("../subdir/build/Release/myAddon");
```

I get an horrible

```
Error: The specified module could not be found.
\\?\C:\Users\MyUserName\path-to-project\subdir\build\Release\myAddon.node
```

But... before that last line above, if I put this:

```
process.chdir("..");
```

Now, I get the add-on to load, but it screws up the rest of the project that rely on the original working directory.

Any work around this? Is it more a *Windows* problem with loading a *DLL*?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, file one at nodejs/node.

Comment: https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge also take a look at this